# Apresentar DIV sobre outra DIV

Tags: javascript, css3, bootstrap-3

Estou usando uma DIV com a mensagem "processando" e fundo opaco, todas as vezes que ocorre uma requisição (iteração do usuário ao clicar em um botão).
Porém, esta tela também é apresentada quando estou com uma tela modal aberta, e acaba acontecendo que a tela de processamento não fica sobreposta sobre a tela modal.
Todo o meu layout foi desenvolvido com Bootstrap 3.
Como faço para sobrepor a div de processamento sobre a modal?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer que fique exatamente como na imagem? Já tentou alterar o Z-index dessa Div de processamento para que o Z-index seja maior que o da Modal?

Comment: O problema é que o z-index que o bootstrap usa é 1050. É padrão para toda Modal

Answer (score 2):

CSS oferece a possibilidade de se trabalhar em camadas nas suas páginas, assim você pode sobrepor elementos uns sobre os outros usando a propriedade z-index...

Como você disse que o bootstrap usa um valor z-index de 1050 você pode alterar isso sobrescrevendo a regra css para o z-index do modal, para fazer isso sua folha de estilo precisa estar abaixo da folha da folha do Bootstrap no seu documento HTML ou então as únicas regras que vão ser sobrescritas são as suas.

Para obter mais informações sobre o uso da propriedade [Clique Aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 0):

A solução é você renderizar o HTML do modal de processamento após o modal de cadastro. Para organizar tudo, segue exemplo:

```
<div id="modalCadastro"></div> 
<div id="modalProcessamento"></div>
```

Quando chamar o modal de processamento, irá sobrepor o outro modal.

Comment: na verdade @Matheus isso já está acontecendo. É o botão confirmar da tela de cadastro que requisita a renderização da tela de processamento.